# Windows 7 Chrome search engine

Tags: google-chrome

When I open incognito in google chrome I an faced with a large photo of a young Chinese. Could be another Asian though.  As far as i know there is no harm done and incognito still works. i wouls prefer to do without it though. Has anyone else had this problem and if so how do i get rid of it.

Comment: Whaaaat? Uhm, I think I'm not the only one who would like to have a screenshot of this. I don't really understand what you mean. And what's the link between incognito mode and a search engine? Your title doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely to be the theme. Just [choose another one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/themes).